# Angular - How to change parent component's content?

Tags: angular

I have a module:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ModuleLayoutComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: ModuleLayoutComponent, children: [
      {path: '/order', component: OrderComponent},
      {path: '/payment', component: PaymentComponent}
    ]}])
  ],

})
```

`ModuleLayoutComponent`:

```js
<header></header>
<div class="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

So how can I, for example, hide `<footer></footer>` if `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` displays `PaymentComponent` i.e. current URL is `/payment`.

Comment: sounds like bad design to me. if `OrderComponent` and `PaymentComponent` should be in different layout contexts, then you should have two different layout components and write your routes accordingly, rather than trying to force parent content to be dependent on a child

Comment: @bryan60 hi. I actually have a lot of components in this module and they all use one layout. But on some pages some elements (arrows, buttons etc) must appear in the footer of this layout.

Comment: again, sounds like you're trying to force multiple layouts to be one, or PERHAPS the footer element actually should be inside the children and not the layout component

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways of doing this:

- having another route + layout component that doesn't have footer, then Order and Payment will be rendered in them
- using ngrx (redux) to have a state for footer visibility, then in Order or Payment dispatch an action to hide footer, then in the layout component listen to state and hide and show footer
- creating a service, with an Observable, in layout component subscribe to observable and hide and show footer by that. Inject the service in the Order and Payment component and call a method to do `next(visibility)` on the Observable (BehabiorSubject) inside the service

Comment: Thank you. Well, I could create different layouts. But this is just an example, I have a lot of components in this module and they all have one layout. But on some pages some elements (arrows, buttons etc) must appear in the footer of this layout. Will service or duplication of ModuleLayoutComponent HTML code be an example of good code? In this case I don't pay attention to DRY (don't repeat yourself).

Comment: I think using ngrx will be a good idea  for solving a problem like this if you hate your own life :P

Answer (score 0):

In the ModuleLayoutComponent you can inject ActivatedRoute. You can use the url observable to get the activated URL. Then you could apply the ngIf directive in your ModuleLayoutComponent template. Like `<footer *ngIf=shouldShow$ | async></footer>`
shouldShow$ could be

> activatedRoute.url.pipe(map(x => x=='payment'))

You could also create a directive if you want this to be applied on different components.
https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute